# Why is JavaScript producing "this" output?

Tags: javascript, this

I have been using JavaScript for some time now, but this particular piece of code has perplexed me a bit.

Why is this the output of the following piece of code

```js
length = 10;
function func() {
  console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  thisFunc: function(func) {
    func();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};

obj.thisFunc(func, 3);
```

producing

```
10
2
```

and not

```
10
5
```

or at least

```
10
10
```

Could somebody explain to me where the value `2` is coming from and what I missed when it comes to `this` in this(no pun intended) particular instance?

Comment: `arguments[0]();` prints `2` because `this` keyword (in this case) refers to `arguments`. So it prints 2, bcoz 2 arguments have been passed, `func` and `3`

Comment: Also, as per https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp, it is best to avoid using length as a variable name as its a reserved word

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle `length` is definitely not a reserved word.

Comment: " You should also avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods: " It is not reserved, and perhaps my wording was incorrect, but it should still be avoided if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Well, length isn't part of objects; only arrays and strings afaik

Comment: I see, makes sense.

Comment: If you added `console.log(this);` inside the `func()` function definition then the answer would present itself to you. When you explicitly call the function `func()` then `this` is the `Window` object. When you use `arguments[0]()` to call the function then `this` refers to `arguments` which is an array with a length of 2 (func, 3).

Comment: @DanNagle It all makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, it is same as doing `console.log(this.length)` anywhere in the global scope. So it will be 10 as you understand.

As mentioned in the comments, [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object is an array-like object which has a property length.

> You can use arguments.length to count how many arguments the function was called with`

In the above quote, the **called with** part is important.

In the second case, the function is run in the context of the `arguments` object. You know that the value of `this` inside a function depends on how it is invoked. Here `this` is the `arguments` object, whose length is 2.

```js
length = 10;
function func() {
  console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  thisFunc: function(func) {
    
    func();
    arguments[0]();
    console.log(arguments.length);
  }
};

obj.thisFunc(func, 3);
console.log(this.length);
```